# Zap proxy not working for a specific site

Tags: zap, zapproxy

I set up Zap proxy. I see it received traffic from other sites except for: http://quiz.aisolutions.com.vn/. It just hung at the login. Tried several ways like changing port number to 8082 but not work

Comment: What's "hung" at login? Please be more specific.

Comment: When press login, it sent request URL: http://quiz-profile-api.aisolutions.com.vn/accounts/login
And show error: Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown

It looks like it was blocked sending

Comment: Does it actually work when ZAP isn't proxying? Are you using a browser launched from ZAP? If so, does it work if HUD is disabled?

Comment: Many tks, it is due to HUD enabled

Comment: Np glad we got it sorted out.

Comment: Added it as an answer to help the next person. Be great if you accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're launching the browser from ZAP then there's a small chance it's because of something that the ZAP HUD is doing (in order to function it injects JS and upgrades some links to https, etc.).

Try disabling HUD, launching a browser, and hitting the site again.

You'll see the HUD Radar Icon [image: HUD Radar Icon/Button] in the toolbar. When the icon is selected the HUD will be added to your browser.
[image]